# Real-world examples of the quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, applications

Does a quadratic equation like $x^2 - ax + y = 0$ describe anything in the real world? (I want to know, if there is something in the same way that $x^2$ is describing a square.)

Comment: Yes. Many many things.

Comment: Any reason why my tag-edit was reverted? This is **not** quadratic-forms.

Comment: Perhaps you can see these examples (there are many others): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Djnwlj6OG9k and http://schoolcenter.gcsnc.com/education/components/board/default.php?sectiondetailid=325947&threadid=13767

Comment: @mrf: It got overwritten by George's suggested edit, which was probably meant for the previous version. I've reapplied your tag changes.

Answer (score 5):

The height $y(t)$ in meters of an object falling under gravity, after $t$ seconds, is given by
$$y(t) = -4.9t^2 + v_0 t + y_0,$$
where $y_0$ is the object's initial height and $v_0$ is the object's initial vertical velocity. In particular, solving for $y(t)=0$ tells you when the object will hit the ground.

Answer (score 2):

Equation  $x^2 - ax + y = 0$ represent for example ($a$ is real parameter) a families of parabolas. Parabola is trajectory of canon ball.

Answer (score 1):

Though not exactly same, depending upon value of a, following situations count as relevant.
For deep explanation, see wikipedia.

1. Bernoulli's Effect. This gives relation of velocity of fluid($u$), Pressure($P$), gravitational constant($g$) and height($h$),  $$\frac{u^2}{g}+P=h$$
2. Mandelbrot Set has Recursive Equation $$P_c=z^2+c, z\in\mathbb{R}$$ which is interesting and creates fractals which appear in nature.
3. The descrete logistics equation is a quadratic equation which surprisingly generates chaos. This is the way population growth (be it bacteria or humans) is calculated.
   $$x_{n+1}=\mu x_n(1-x_n)$$
4. Schrodinger's Equation
5. Motion of Projectile as already mentioned

**ed infinitum**